# ROS implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm to shortest path

Tags: c++, pathfinding

I am making a ros node to implement dijkstra's algorithm on a 1000x1000 pixel map.

I have used map_server to convert the map into an nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.

The map is in the form of a row dominant matrix and I have declared visited, distance and prev in the same form. Distance stores the distance of each index and is initially declared with a huge number. visited is a bool array storing whether that index has been visited or not. prev stores the shortest path followed.

struct node is initialised to make a priority queue storing node and distance in increasing order.

void dijkstra is the function that does the heavy loading in this program.

What I'm looking for if there are any blind spots I'm not considering and if there are some optimisations.

````
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>
#include <nav_msgs/GetMap.h>
#include <ros/console.h>
#define FMAX 999999999.99

    geometry_msgs::PoseArray pa;
    int rows = 1000, columns = 1000, size = rows * columns;
    bool visited[1000000];
    float distance[1000000];
    int prev[1000000];
    int source = 15100, destination = 990500; // Give source and destination
    int dr[] = {1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1}; // Direction vectors
    int dc[] = {0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1};
    struct node
    {
        int index;
        float dist;
        node(int index, float dist)
            : index(index), dist(dist)
        {
        } 
    };
    struct compareDist
    {
        bool operator()(node const& n1, node const& n2)
        {
            return n1.dist > n2.dist;
        }
    };

    // Priority queue
    std::priority_queue <node, std::vector<node>, compareDist> pq;

    int index(int r, int c)
    {
        return (r * 1000) + c;
    }

    void init()
    {
        std::cout << "init";
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            distance[i] = FMAX;
            visited[i] = false;
            prev[i] = 99999999;
        }   
    }

    float dist_(int index1, int index2)
    {
        int r1, c1, r2, c2;
        r1 = index1 / columns; r2 = index2 / columns;
        c1 = index1 - (r1 * 1000); c2 = index2 - (r2 * 1000);
        return sqrt(pow(r1 - r2, 2) + pow(c1 - c2, 2));
    }

    void dijkstra(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& map)
    {
        prev[source] = 0;
        node first = {source, 0.0}; // Define source
        pq.push(first);
        while(!pq.empty())
        {
            node temp = pq.top();
            pq.pop();
            int nodeIndex = temp.index;
            float nodeDist = temp.dist;
            visited[nodeIndex] = true;
            int r = nodeIndex / columns;
            int c = nodeIndex - (r * columns);
            int rr, cc;
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // to calculate neighbours
            {
                rr = r + dr[i];
                cc = c + dc[i];

                if(rr < 0 || rr >= 1000 || cc < 0 || cc >= 1000 || visited[index(rr, cc)] == true)
                    continue;

                if(map.data[index(rr, cc)] == 100)
                {
                    visited[index(rr, cc)] = true; // Marking blocked paths as visited
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    node neighbour(index(rr, cc), dist_(nodeIndex, index(rr, cc)));
                    float alt = nodeDist + neighbour.dist;
                    if(alt < distance[index(rr, cc)])
                    {
                        visited[index(rr, cc)] = true;
                        distance[index(rr, cc)] = alt;
                        prev[index(rr, cc)] = nodeIndex;
                        node next(index(rr, cc), alt);

                        pq.push(next);
                    }
                    if(visited[destination] == true)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(visited[destination] == true)
                break;
        }

        std::vector <int> path;
        // prev contains the path. Trace it back to get the path.
        path.push_back(destination);
        while(true)
        {
            path.push_back(prev[path.back()]);
            if(path.back() == 0)
                break;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++)
        {
            int x, y;
            x = path.back() / columns;
            y = path.back() - (x * columns);
            path.pop_back();
            geometry_msgs::Pose p;
            p.position.x = x;
            p.position.y = y;
            p.position.z = 0;
            pa.poses.push_back(p);
        }

    }



    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        init();
        distance[source] = 0;
        visited[source] = true;
        ros::init(argc, argv, "dijkstra");
        ros::NodeHandle n("~");
        ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetMap>("/static_map");
        nav_msgs::GetMap srv;
        client.call(srv);
        nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid my_map = srv.response.map;
        ros::Publisher pose_array_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/poseArray", 1);
        pa.header.frame_id = "map";
        dijkstra(my_map);

        while(ros::ok())
        {
            pose_array_pub.publish(pa);
        }
        ros::spin();    
    }
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of global variables. That works for a one-off program, but if you ever want to package your functionality into a library or so, you need to rewrite this to put them into the main program. Might as well do so immediately. (In particular your "dijkstra" function should return an explicit result. Not be void and work on a global variable.)

You declare a couple of large static arrays. 1. That's wasteful for smaller problems. 2. Your program will crash if you try something larger. 3. You are putting them on the stack so this runs into problems if your OS limits the stack size. Conclusion: please make them dynamic. std::vector is great for this. That also prevents you from having lots of "magic numbers" in your code.

"if(visited[destination] == true)" You know that that's the same as 
`if(visited[destination])`?

Algorithm optimizations? If you implemented it correctly it'll probably be fine.